# Force to close an already open file for copying

Tags: r, file, io, copy

I need to copy a file.

Say , I have this code:

```
outputFile <- 'Path1/out.pdf'
originFile <- 'Path2/origin.pdf'

file.copy(from =originFile, to = outputFile,overwrite=TRUE)
```

But , if out.pdf (destination file) is already open I have a **permission denied** exception.

How can I do to force closing/removing destination file before the new copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using close or something similar does not help in that case, because you do not have an handle to `out.pdf` opened for example in Acrobat Reader.

There a two ways around this problem (assuming Windows, I do not know how to handle this in other systems).

a) Use Sumatra Viewer; it's the only reasonably reliable viewer that does not put a lock on the pdf file. It's the method used by RStudio.

b) Use `pdfpos` via a system() call to close the file. See [here](http://dererumnatura.us/archives/2006/03/texniccenter-an.html) for an example. I used this method before RStudio came along, but it needs tweaking on each new release  of Acrobat Reader/Full Version, and a running perl installation. Should work on other operating systems.

Comment: thanks! but do you have a code example where you use Sumatra Viewer?

Comment: No code required, install Sumatra Viewer and define it as the standard viewer. If you do not want to do this, use method 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `?close` - these are the commands to manage file connections within R. `close(outputFile)` may be all you need. `closeAllConnections()` nukes the lot if you have several files open at the same time.

(Of course, if the file has been opened by another program outside of R, e.g. a pdf reader, you will have to close it outside of R.)